# Hinduism sacred texts written outside India?

Tags: scripture, history

Ramayana and Mahabharata the two epics were composed in India in ancient times. Afterwards they reached in different parts of the World like Indonesia and Bali.People on those parts accepted and absorbed these hindu texts as part of their culture.

Like wise are there any hindu sacred texts (about hinduism only) written outside of India in those times and got absorbed or became part of hindu holy texts or grantha?

Not from recent times but from thousands of years back.

Comment: Yes , there is a possibility that some part of Hinduism scriptutes got  written in adjacent countries like nepal and Gandhar (Afghanistan) , Shri Lanka etc.and later got accepted , included in scriptures written over here.

Comment: But i think we surely don't know about which modern day countries were part of Bharat-Varsha mentioned in Puranas.